# Why does my Action Bar not overlay?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am new to Android development. I have followed the Android Overlay training at:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

and spent the last few days trying to get this to work. I am using the AppCompat library and my min SDK is 7 and my max sdk is 18.

My application defines a custom style and looks like this:

```
<application

android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >

<activity
android:name="com.example.rtrt.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
```

My layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/button_send"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/clickme"
android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My theme.xml looks like this:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"  
parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item> 
</style>      <!-- ActionBar styles -->

<style name="MyActionBar"            
parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">

<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>

<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>   
</style>
```

The application compiles and runs... however, the `Button` appears below (not under) the `ActionBar`. When I hide the `ActionBar` the `Button` moves to the top of the screen. When the `ActionBar` is made visible, the Button is repositioned down the screen.

Why is my `ActionBar` not floating (overlaying)?

Would appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are targeting below SDK 11.

change your theme to AppCompat and not AppCompat.Light:

```
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```